# Parallax demo for mobile

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, parallax

This is hands down the best parallax functionality I've seen on mobile/iOS before: http://www.buccirestaurant.com.au/#about

I've come across other libraries which do it but are a bit jittery on the mobile, but this thing is smooth and elegant.

Unfortunately their source code is extremely difficult to decode and make sense of, wouldn't even know where to begin with pulling it apart to make my own library. I'm wondering if anyone out there:

A) By chance has a copy of the library that I could use?
B) Could assist in recreating the library?
C) Has an alternative library they've used themselves which is smooth on iPhone?

Thanks

Comment: Probably they're just using CSS z-depth. Here's a pretty good article on how to achieve the same effect, no javascript required: http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/

Comment: [Here's](http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/recreate-nikebetterworld-parallax/) a smooth Jquery API I have used before, note that it is no longer updated. Otherwise [this](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/) seems like a brilliant alternative ([github link](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr)). I advise the use of JavaScript, as it is better supported for older browsers - that said it's personal choice as to whether you choose to support older browsers anyway.